# Trouble with CHOWN

Tags: chown

Used Testdisk to recover deleted files. Selected directory /Downloads.
But Testdisk saved all files to /home/.Trash-1000/expunged
All files have a lock symbol Cant copy these files nor open them. Owner is specified as root.
Changed to root using sudo -i, get a response "No such file or directory"
When I use ls command, directories which start with .  such as .TraSH-1000 or .cache are not listed.
How to change ownership of these files in .Trash-1000

Comment: `ls` hides "dotfiles" by default - you'll need `ls -A` or `ls -a` to see them

Comment: `CHOWN` is not an existing command. Do you mean `chown`? If yes, then please correct the title of your question.